# Explain the printed values of method expressions

Tags: go, memory-address, func, reflect

The following code tries to show the address of a method associated to struct.

```
package  main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type II interface {
    Callme()
}

type Str struct {
    I int
    S string
}

func (s *Str) Callme () {
    fmt.Println("it is me")
}

func main() {
    s0 := &Str{}
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s0)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s0)
    fmt.Println("Callme ", s0.Callme)   //real address ?
    fmt.Println(t.Method(0).Name, v.Method(0))    //real address ?

    s1 := &Str{}
    t1 := reflect.TypeOf(s1)
    v1 := reflect.ValueOf(s1)
    fmt.Println("Callme ", s1.Callme)   //real address ?
    fmt.Println(t1.Method(0).Name, v1.Method(0))    //real address ?
}
```

The output is :

```
Callme  0x4bc2d0
Callme 0x4ab2c0
Callme  0x4bc2d0
Callme 0x4ab2c0
```

So I have two questions:

- First, why these statements do not show identical values ?

  ```
  fmt.Println("Callme ", s0.Callme)
  fmt.Println(t.Method(0).Name, v.Method(0))
  ```
- Second, why these statements show identical values ?

  ```
  fmt.Println(t.Method(0).Name, v.Method(0))    
  fmt.Println(t1.Method(0).Name, v1.Method(0))
  ```

Comment: You are printing with fmt.Println which does a lot of magic. Magic you must understand (e.g. it calls String methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fmt` package calls [Value.Pointer](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Pointer) to get function addresses.

Let's look at an example of what `Value.Pointer` returns for the functions:

```
s0 := &Str{}
v0 := reflect.ValueOf(s0)
fmt.Printf("s0.Callme: %0x %0x\n", reflect.ValueOf(s0.Callme).Pointer(), s0.Callme)
fmt.Printf("v0.Method(0) %0x %0x\n", v0.Method(0).Pointer(), v0.Method(0))

s1 := &Str{}
v1 := reflect.ValueOf(s1)
fmt.Printf("s1.Callme %x %x\n", reflect.ValueOf(s1.Callme).Pointer(), s1.Callme)
fmt.Printf("v1.Method(0) %x %x\n", v1.Method(0).Pointer(), v1.Method(0))
```

The output is:

```
s0.Callme: 105240 105240
v0.Method(0) eee60 eee60
s1.Callme 105240 105240
v1.Method(0) eee60 eee60
```

This matches the pattern shown in the question.

The [function related code for Value.Pointer](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8d2e65d22408e9e1c6329485baf432be9300f410/src/reflect/value.go#L1375-L1392) is:

```
    if v.flag&flagMethod != 0 {
        // As the doc comment says, the returned pointer is an
        // underlying code pointer but not necessarily enough to
        // identify a single function uniquely. All method expressions
        // created via reflect have the same underlying code pointer,
        // so their Pointers are equal. The function used here must
        // match the one used in makeMethodValue.
        f := methodValueCall
        return **(**uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
    }
    p := v.pointer()
    // Non-nil func value points at data block.
    // First word of data block is actual code.
    if p != nil {
        p = *(*unsafe.Pointer)(p)
    }
    return uintptr(p)
```

A `reflect.Value` created through a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) in the reflect API has the `flagMethod` method bit set.  As the comment states and the code shows, the Pointer method returns the same value for all method expressions created this way.

The `reflect.Value` created by `relect.ValueOf(s1.Callme)` does not have the `flagMethod` method bit set. In this case, the function returns the pointer to the actual code.

The output of [this program](https://play.golang.org/p/XfV4zQ2ykih) shows all of the combinations:

```
type StrA struct {
    I int
    S string
}

func (s *StrA) Callme() {
    fmt.Println("it is me")
}

type StrB struct {
    I int
    S string
}

func (s *StrB) Callme() {
    fmt.Println("it is me")
}

s0A := &StrA{}
v0A := reflect.ValueOf(s0A)
s1A := &StrA{}
v1A := reflect.ValueOf(s0A)

fmt.Println("s0A.Callme ", reflect.ValueOf(s0A.Callme).Pointer())
fmt.Println("v0A.Method(0) ", v0A.Method(0).Pointer())
fmt.Println("s1A.Callme ", reflect.ValueOf(s1A.Callme).Pointer())
fmt.Println("v1A.Method(0) ", v1A.Method(0).Pointer())

s0B := &StrB{}
v0B := reflect.ValueOf(s0B)
s1B := &StrB{}
v1B := reflect.ValueOf(s0B)

fmt.Println("s0B.Callme ", reflect.ValueOf(s0B.Callme).Pointer())
fmt.Println("v0B.Method(0) ", v0B.Method(0).Pointer())
fmt.Println("s1B.Callme ", reflect.ValueOf(s1B.Callme).Pointer())
fmt.Println("v1B.Method(0) ", v1B.Method(0).Pointer())
```

Output:

```
s0A.Callme  1061824
v0A.Method(0)  978528
s1A.Callme  1061824
v1A.Method(0)  978528
s0B.Callme  1061952
v0B.Method(0)  978528
s1B.Callme  1061952
v1B.Method(0)  978528
```

We can observe that Value.Pointer returns the same value for all [method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) created through the reflect API.  This includes methods on different types.

We can also observe that `Value.Pointer` returns the same value for all [method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) on a given type and method. This is true for method expressions bound to different values.

The [Value.Pointer documentation](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Pointer) says:

> If v's Kind is Func, the returned pointer is an underlying code pointer, but not necessarily enough to identify a single function uniquely. The only guarantee is that the result is zero if and only if v is a nil func Value.

Given this, an application cannot reliably use Value.Pointer or printed values through the `fmt` package to compare functions and methods.